# What is difference between periodic & oscillatory motions?

Tags: kinematics, terminology, definition

I read about two motions of objects

1. Periodic motion &
2. Oscillatory motion.

Are they same motion? If not what is the basic difference between these two motions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In simple words,

A periodic motion is one which repeats itself after certain period of time

Example: Motion of Earth around the sun is a periodic motion

An oscillatory motion is to and fro motion about a mean position.

Example: Motion of pendulum (which is also a SHM)

The second motion is subset of first one i.e. each oscillatory motion is a periodic motion but vice versa is not true.

Answer (score 0):

I would add to above answer, that typically a oscillation happens, when energy is transformed from one to another form and vice versa and therefore keeping the motion running.

For a periodic movement the most important is the periodic behaviour in time. Therefore this "definition" has other restrictions than the former.